Black Outline Issue Around Text with CSS Gradient
I'm trying to create text with a gradient effect using CSS, but I'm noticing that there's a black outline around the letters, which is not the desired effect. Here’s the CSS I'm using:
div.marge { height: 100vh; }
* { font-size: 50px; color: black; }

span.white {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(27deg, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 255, 255, 1) 100%) no-repeat,
                linear-gradient(27deg, #000000 0%, #000000 100%) no-repeat;
    background-size: 125% 100%, 100% 100%;
    background-position: 0% 50%, 0% 50%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


You can see an example of this issue on my CodePen : https://codepen.io/Smartson/pen/wvVdWjV
I would like to know how I can remove this black outline while keeping the colorful gradient on the text. Do you have any suggestions to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I've tried using text-shadow and text-stroke, but they haven't resolved the issue.

I do not see this in Chrome. Can you please click [edit] then the button marked [<>] and post a [mcve] here at SO so it does not get lost when you delete or change the codepen

I do not see this in Edge/WIndows11. What browser, device and OS are you using?

The issue you're experiencing is likely due to the second linear-gradient in your background property, which creates a black overlay that might be causing the black outline effect around your gradient text.
Here’s an updated version of your CSS, where I've removed the extra black gradient, while keeping the colorful gradient and ensuring no black outline appears around the text:
        div.marge {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        * {
            font-size: 50px;
            color: black;
        }

        span.white {
            text-decoration: none;
            background: linear-gradient(27deg, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(43, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
            background-size: 125% 100%;
            background-position: 0% 50%;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            padding: 0 2px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

Key changes:
I removed the second linear-gradient (the one with #000000), which was likely responsible for the black outline effect.
The -webkit-background-clip: text; and -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; properties remain to ensure that the text only shows the gradient background without any fill color.

Thank you for your response.
The problem is that I need this black gradient to create a filling effect for the word with GSAP. I tried using a span tag in absolute position and applying clip-path over it, but it doesn't work well responsively.

@MaximeDeranty you asked your question regarding issue with black outline, and this solution has solved it appropriately, now youre asking something totally different, to use black gradient and create filling effect, responsiveness which doesn't seem to be nice, you may ask a different question regarding what you really need, as far as i see this answer matches exactly with your current question
